# Listview items loosing changes on scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

**My Need :**

I want to implement a list of variables which can have dynamic no of rows. 
this list contains 3 TextViews,1 ImageView, 3ImageButtons.

User can select a row by tap. On long tap multiple items can be selected. On selection the selected row UI will be changed. selected item change its background and image of imageview and one Image button will be visible on selection.

As user tap on the ImageButton Image will be change of image button and the other Image buttons also become visible

if some items already selected and user try to select a single row by tapping all other selected items will be removed. listview items should come into its original condition. like Imageview will be reset with its default image and Imagebutton ll be disappear.

**What i tried :**

I try to implement a ListView using Base adapter. Define a custom row for the need of 3 TextViews, 1 ImageView and 3 ImageButton.

```
package com.astron.myapplication;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.astron.myapplication.R;
import com.astron.myapplication.TSSVariableInfo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.view.View;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    TSSVariableInfo info[];
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, TSSVariableInfo[] results) {
        info = new TSSVariableInfo[results.length];
        info = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return info.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return info[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        DateFormat dateFormatFrom ;
        DateFormat dateFormatTo;
        Boolean  IsRolSeleted = false;


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.VariableCustomerGivenName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CustomerGivenName);
            holder.VariableStandardName =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.StanddardName);
            holder.VariableSectionName =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SectionName);
            holder.VariableValue =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LastValue);
            holder.VariableLastDate =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LastDate);
            holder.VariableLegendImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImgLegend);
            holder.VariableLegendImage.setTag(0);
            holder.BtnMore = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnMore) ;
            holder.BtnMore.setTag(0);
            holder.BtnY2 = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn2y) ;
            holder.BtnTL = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnTL) ;

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E8E8E8"));

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        holder.VariableCustomerGivenName.setText(info[position].VariableCustomerGivenName);
        holder.VariableStandardName.setText(info[position].VariableStandarName);
        holder.VariableSectionName.setText(info[position].SectionName);
        holder.VariableValue.setText(info[position].Value.toString());
        dateFormatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
        dateFormatTo =  new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
        java.util.Date dt;
        String strdt = info[position].LastDate;

            dt = dateFormatFrom.parse(strdt);
            dateFormatTo.format(dt);
            holder.VariableLastDate.setText(dateFormatTo.format(dt));

        //holder.VariableLastDate.setText(dateFormatTo.format(dateFormatFrom.format(info[position].LastDate)));

        if(info[position].VariableCustomerGivenName.isEmpty() || info[position].VariableCustomerGivenName==null) {
            holder.VariableCustomerGivenName.setText(info[position].VariableStandarName);
            holder.VariableStandardName.setText(info[position].SectionName);
            holder.VariableSectionName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
            holder.VariableSectionName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.BtnMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        return convertView;
    }
    public void updateAdapter(TSSVariableInfo[] results) {
        this.info= results;

        //and call notifyDataSetChanged
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView VariableCustomerGivenName;
        TextView VariableStandardName;
        TextView VariableSectionName;
        TextView VariableValue;
        TextView VariableLastDate;
        ImageView VariableLegendImage;
        ImageButton BtnMore;
        ImageButton BtnY2;
        ImageButton BtnTL;
    }
```

My onClick

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

((ImageButton)((LinearLayout) arg1).getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.btnMore)).setTag("1");
                    ((ImageButton)((LinearLayout) arg1).getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.btnMore)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ImageView imgLegend = ((ImageView) ((LinearLayout) arg1).getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.ImgLegend));
 setImageForLegend(imgLegend, info[position].VariableID);
});
```

**Facing Problem :**

After selection of single row on scrolling of ListView Some Other items showing the change which i made for the single row.

Comment: How do you use `IsRolSeleted`?

Comment: not using it for now.

Comment: catch (Exception ex){} is a very, very bad idea

Comment: Okay, can you post your onItemClick() or whatever you are using to handle the row selection?

Comment: I think it is interesting that you have buttons in your rows, but are listening for clicks on the entire row instead of on the buttons..  can you explain why?

Comment: yes i want two things to implement. 1. When user select a row then One ImageButton will be appear on selected row. 2. When user click on visible button of the selected row it will perform another action.

Comment: @ryguy anything i can do to resolve this problem

Comment: If it were me, I would implement a custom adapter. This would allow you to setup the onClick for the button in the adapter. Have you ever done this?

Comment: yes, as you can see in my code custom adapter implemented.not getting you what exactly you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, dont use `array[]` use `bean` class and `getter setter` and `ArrayList` to bind `ListView` items
take a reference of below link how they did custom ListView using SQLite database

http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-list-view-using-custom-adapter.html

to maintain changes you need to set your changes in `bean` class
may you need to change all your code but this only way help you.

may my answer will confuse because you dont know the way.
please follow above link read carefully and do implementation.